# Forcing encoding on bad XML files with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, encoding

A big set of XML files have the wrong encoding defined. It should be utf-8 but the content has latin-1 characters all over the place. What's the best way to parse this content?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Edit: this is happening with Adobe InDesign IDML files, it seems the "Content" text has latin-1 but the rest could be utf-8. I'm favoring normal parsing with utf-8, then reencode the Unicode text chunks in Content to utf-8 and then re-parsing with latin-1. What a mess.
ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the encoding specified in the XML when you parse it:

> ```
> class xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser(html=0, target=None, encoding=None)
> ```
>
> `Element`
>   structure builder for XML source data,
>   based on the expat parser. html are
>   predefined HTML entities. This flag is
>   not supported by the current
>   implementation. `target` is the target
>   object. If omitted, the builder uses
>   an instance of the standard
>   TreeBuilder class. encoding [1](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser) is
>   optional. If given, the value
>   overrides the encoding specified in
>   the XML file.

[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser)

Comment: Ah, I tried this but got an error. Seems it's new in python 2.7. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to deal with encoding problems during parse, but pre-process the offending file(s).

Comment: It might be more complicated than I thought and there might be some real UTF-8 stuff in the files. I will have to un-encode from Unicode to utf-8, and then force reparsing on latin-1 for the specific places it might happen.